# Using speech-to-text in non-WebKit browsers

Tags: html, browser

By applying the `x-webkit-speech` attrtibute to an `<input type="text" />` element, you can let WebKit browsers like Chrome use speech-to-text.

This way a user can speak to enter text in the textbox.

Which attribute can I use on other browsers to obtain the same effect?

Comment: [`x-webkit-speech` is deprecated now.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23188951/552067)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789249/cross-browser-speech-recognition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this feature is only implemented in Chrome for Win/Mac/Android. That's because it's invented by Google and relies on Google's server to do the voice recognition. Any other browsers who want to implement this feature need to acquire voice recognition technology or work with a partner who has this technology. Thus I don't think this feature will be widely implemented in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is the only desktop browser I'm aware of which currently implements speech input. Might also work in the Android browser, but I'm not sure. It's definitely not implemented in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

x-webkit-speech is now deprecated. We should use

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.onresult = function(event) { 
  console.log(event) 
}
recognition.start();
```

Both firefox & Edge are developing **speechRecognition()**

http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition