# Speech recognition in browsers other than Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

How can I access a microphone using JavaScript or HTML5 without using Flash? I made it work in Chrome using `webkit-speech`. I need to do it in other browsers. Any answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature proposed by Google, and appears to only be supported in their products.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6619632/1504847

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial. It may help you. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

At this point, it only expands your options to opera however... For Firefox and IE (along with others like Midori, ect) you will still need to rely on plugins.... Hopefully as HTML5 gets closer to being an official standard, we will see widespread support.

Answer (score 0):

- `x-webkit-speech` works only for Chrome
- there is a html5 attribute with the same purpose: `speech`.
  However right now it doesn't work neither on Chrome 31.xx neither on Firefox 25

This is [w3c doc page](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html) for the `<input>` attribute `speech`

Answer (score -1):

Look at this project: https://github.com/TalAter/annyang

It is quite good SpeechRecognition library. You can see how it was done.

Comment: annyang only works in Chrome. While the code is using different prefixes, it is only there to ensure forward compatibility.