# Adding voice search functionality on mobile we application

Tags: android, ios, html, css, mobile

I have created a mobile web application using HTML5 and CSS3, it's doesn't have any native feature. Now, I need to provide voice search functionality in my app. I explored and find that google has launched one 'google voice app' for all the platforms. My questions is - Can I add this functionality in my pure mobile web application or it has to be a native call to recognize the voice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this : [Speech Input](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input)

Chrome supports speech recognition for text input. You can use this by using this in your HTML

`<input type=”text” speech x-webkit-speech />`

[image]

Comment: yeah exactly sanjay ..thanks very much...but how can I do the similiar thing for safari in IPhone and other mobile browsers.

Comment: Well I got my answer here - Thanks Sanjay for your help though.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606182/what-are-the-x-webkit-speech-alternatives