# input type text with speech recognition for firefox

Tags: html, input, speech-recognition

I have one input type text field, with the attribute **x-webkit-speech**.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" x-webkit-speech>
```

It works well in chrome, but not in firefox.
Anyone does know if is it supported by any way, in firefox?

Edit : is there any js / bootstrap plugin available?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x-webkit-speech` will only work in chrome. the google team using their technology and servers. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6619632/2609485))

Answer (score 0):

- `x-webkit-speech` works only for Chrome
- there is a html5 attribute with the same purpose: `speech`.
  However right now it doesn't work neither on Chrome 31.xx neither on Firefox 25

This is [w3c doc page](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html) for the `<input>` attribute `speech`