# x-webkit-speech is deprectated. A JS replacement for simple speech input for <input>?

Tags: javascript, speech-to-text

I noticed this warning in Chrome devtool's console:

> The `x-webkit-speech` input field attribute is deprecated. Please use the JavaScript API instead.

So what's the best JS API replacement for simple speech input on input fields?

Perhaps there exists a drop-in JS module that will handle it for me?

Comment: @Teemu I've certainly done some Googling around.

Comment: A google search for your error msg verbatim gave this up in about 2 minutes: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API

Comment: @enhzflep Yeah, I read that article more than once. It's a nice intro to the web speech API, but nothing close to a drop in replacement for the `x-webkit-speech` attribute.

Comment: For the ones, who want to know, why attribute was deprecated: It was a security vulnerability in Chrome till M35: https://blogs.janestreet.com/disabling-chromes-x-webkit-speech-vulnerability/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Answering my own question:**

Just made a Github project for this purpose: https://github.com/Daniel-Hug/speech-input

Answer (score 7):

There is a JavaScript [SpeechRecognition API](http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/) that does text-to-speech and speech-to-text. Not many browsers support it but Chrome should have support.