# Speech input doesn't work with Google Custom Search - Chrome 37

Tags: google-chrome, voice-recognition, google-custom-search

Speech input doesn't work with Google Custom Search on Chrome 37, the mic doesn't even show. What am I missing? I understand x-webkit-speech tag has been deprecated, but is there something to replace it?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [x-webkit-speech is deprectated. A JS replacement for simple speech input for <input>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188951/x-webkit-speech-is-deprectated-a-js-replacement-for-simple-speech-input-for-in)

Comment: I saw that, but I though maybe there should be a specific solution for Google's CSE (since you already import their js code...)