# Is there a way to activate Siri from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, siri

Is there a way to trigger Siri from a webpage (perhaps using Javascript), to fill an input text field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably cannot trigger Siri directly but you can use the `x-webkit-speech` html5 input type which will add the ability to use voice input:

`<input type="text" x-webkit-speech>`

It should be available in mobile safari as well: http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-speech

For more information you could e.g. refer to: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/accepting-speech-input-html5-forms

Comment: You can check the support of voice input by running this snippet in mobile safari: `alert(document.createElement('input').webkitSpeech !== undefined)` . If it returns `true` you should be able to use it, if it returns `false` not. Unfortunately there seems to be very little information about voice input for mobile safari out there...

Comment: `x-webkit-speech` is deprecated. See this StackOverflow [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188951/x-webkit-speech-is-deprectated-a-js-replacement-for-simple-speech-input-for-in) for an alternate solution.